# Stripes between 2 images of Sentinel 2A (Level-1C)

Tags: mosaic, sentinel-2, date

Why do i get these stripes between 2 images of Sentinel 2A? (Figure)

[image]

I notice that this happened for 2 images of different sensing date (even they're just 3 days away).

Has anyone had this problem and solved it?

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to be entirely sure, without more information, but consider setting all bands to no-data if any of the included bands is no-data / 0. That usually fixes many of the image-border issues seen in remote sensing.
This problem usually arises when the sensor from one band provides slightly more information than the other sensors.

If that does not solve it, look into which values you are seeing in those pixels and consider if you are including more spectral bands in your mosaic than what you are actually showing in the illustration.